# Is it possible to reopen an anonymous module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to reopen an anonymous module in Ruby?  The following does not work:

```
m = Module.new
module m
end
```

"SyntaxError: (eval):2: class/module name must be CONSTANT".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. But you have to use a constant.

```
M = Module.new
module M
end
```

You can also do `M = m`.

---

Another way:

```
m = Module.new do
  def self.foo1
    1
  end
end

m.class_eval do
  def self.foo2
    2
  end
end

m.foo1 + m.foo2  #=> 3
```

Comment: If i use a constant, the module is not anonymous: `M.name # => 'M'`

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, `class_eval`/`instance_eval` is the only way?

Comment: Of course, you can also use other metaprogramming methods like `define_method` on an anonymous module.